# ¿Cómo puedo poner la imagen completa dentro de un div?

Tags: html, css, html5

Hice un div con la clase team-box-bg-1 que es la que contiene la imagen de fondo de cada personal.

```
.team-box-bg-1{
    background: url(../../assets/images/team/team1.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

Pero la imagen se ve cortada, es decir no se presencia toda la imagen dentro del div

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el HTML de la imagen

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="single-team-box team-box-bg-1">
        <div class="team-box-inner">
            <h3>Nombre</h3>
            <p class="team-meta">Founder &  CEO</p>
            <a href="team.html" class="learn-btn">
                Ver más
            </a>
        </div><!--/.team-box-inner-->

    </div><!--/.single-team-box-->
</div><!--.col-->
```

Comment: Prueba agregándole la propiedad `background-size: contain;`. Quizá también te interese usar `background-position: top` para que se vea la cara que es lo más importante y simplemente ignoras lo que pase con el cuerpo. Si no queda como quieres, posiblemente `col-sm-3` y `col-xs-12` o algún otro estilo esté limitando el espacio que tiene la foto para mostrarse.

Comment: le quito el center entonces?

Comment: Ha funcionado, gracias

Comment: Podrías usar las propiedades individuales del [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#constituent_properties) para que sea más fácil distinguir entre cada una. En especial si usas muchas. Ya que `background` permite escribir las otras de forma reducida aunque hace más difícil la lectura.